# Undo command chown

Tags: magento-1.9, linux

After giving ownership `chown -R {username}:{username} folder/` to a specific folder in Magento all other domains in the same VPS do not allows me to upload images.

Is it possible to undo this command or set its default value to all domains because finally that was not an ownership problem?

Comment: Yes simply use the same command and this time use the default user and user-group.

Comment: What is the default user and usergroup?
I connected as root and went into example.com ans typed chown -R example:example folder/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with Magento.

Comment: You need to contact your hosting provider to get the default user and user group. This changes from host to host.

Answer (score 1):

There is no possible way to undo a chown command.

What you can do is run the chown command again with the user and group that previously owned the files.

If you don't know which user was that then it may be better to **contact your hosting company** because the users vary from host to host. Additionally you can find what user apache is running as: `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'`